# What do you call the truest subjective truths?

Tags: terminology

What do you call the truest subjective truths? There are objective truth such as "Markus scored an IQ of 90 on the Raven Matrices test" and subjective truth such as "Markus is dumb", but there are truths that are subjective but extremely true or universally true or true in the sense most people would agree. "Markus is dumb, because he scored 85 on several IQ tests". What do you call these types of subjective truths. Do we even distinguish between different subjective truths?

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Your question hinges on the use of [weasal words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word). In what way do you propose "truest", "extremely true" have meaning?

Comment: @CriglCragl, my point in mentioning definitions was to show language has no bearing on if any Proposition — let’s use proposition X here for now— is either true or false.  No one should challenge a definition and claim they have disproved the relevant proposition under discussion whatever that is.  So your use of cyborgs or minds uploaded into the cloud, etc would not change the essence of a proposition. Propositions are not physical as sentences. You may take sentences too literally.  If you do then your definition of what a proposition is not lined up in Philosophy but something else.

Comment: If it is subjective, in what sense it is Truth? And *not* a personal opinion?

Answer (score 1):

For me they are truths about what is universal to being a mind & awareness itself. Because as I see it, following [Indra's Net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_net) & the Private Language Argument, I would argue there is no subjectivity extended by language, without intersubjectivity.

It is how much we can universalise the quality of having a perspective and narrating from it, our ability to share that and speak to each other as though we were them, which underlies all our abilities to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your IQ test examples are not really good for several reasons. First of all it's still hotly debated as to what IQ tests measure in the first place and if that is an appropriate mean to measure someone's intelligence. Secondly it's not really a objective scale of values but just a measurement of spread within a cohort. That's why you get your Gaussian, bell curve or normal distribution. So it doesn't mean you're intelligent or dumb, but rather checks your performance on a test compared to the other people who took the test.

Also afaik the bell curve is designed so that 68.2% (or let's say a majority of people) fit within the range of 85-115. In other words that would still be more or less average. Maybe a little below average but still.

But again that is the spread within a cohort. Even if the test would measure intelligence (which again is often dubious), you'd not measure an objective property but just a relation between people. So a test on smart people where you are the dumbest might still not mean that you're not capable of anything, but could just mean you're 0.001% slower than the rest or whatnot while a test whereas if you make a test including word comprehension in kindergarten or before and end up on top (because you're the only one way older) doesn't mean you're actually smart.

That's the first problem the second is that even if you'd assume that this test could measure an objective property and that it's not a relation value but a points value than your statement "Markus is dumb, because he scored 85 on several IQ tests" would still be problematic. A because this doesn't follow like the test is not the reason that Markus is dumb the test is just used to confirm that suspicion but Markus either is or isn't dumb regardless of whether you test it. And the other is that this is still not a subjective statement. It's still claiming that Markus' lack of intelligence is an objective fact not a subjective assessment.

And second of all what even is the truest subjective truths in the first place? And I don't mean an example but as a concept. Like what is this supposed to be?

First of all "truest truth" as a concept makes no sense either it is true or it isn't and if you're talking about something that is only correct under conditions or within a margin of error than you'd avoid calling that truth to begin with.

And the next thing is "true according to what"? Like a subjectively held believe that is objectively true? Or the most fundamental of all subjective believes? Like idk "cogito ergo sum" (I think therefore I am"?

The problem is that if a subjective believe is universal, then it's no longer a subjective believe but for the sake of that group in which it is universal, it would be an objective believe because others could also see it and it's not constraint to the POV of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by truest subjective truths? Subjective truths are always true to the utterer; eg ‘I have a headache.’ - only I can know. If I’m telling the truth, it’s a subjective truth.

I’m not sure about Markus’s IQ being subjective - if it was recorded on a test then objectively he scored a certain mark? Compared to others, he objectively scored less than them and then a label ‘dumb’ is attached to him - which is not an objective observation of his abilities but simply placing a word on him: this will be a subjective to the person who labels him - and their own subjective hierarchy of ‘intelligence’.

If you mean it’s subjective in the sense that we can’t know if Markus objectively has a low IQ or whether he was scoring low on the test on purpose - then that would be a subjective falsity on his part, not a truth.

Answer (score 0):

I find the idea that truth is a sliding scale, at least in this context, somewhat difficult to swallow.

Regardless of objectivity or subjectivity, true is true and false is false; they are Boolean values.

**Components of a statement** can be true or false, and a statement can contain a mixture of the two, but are ultimately reducible to boolean truth or fallacy.

For example, take the statement:
"Yesterday, the sun rose and set in the East."

It's true that yesterday, the sun rose in the East.
It is not true that the sun set in the East.

However, to say the statement is "half true" or "half false" is entirely misguided. The entire statement is false, even if it contains components of truth. It is misleading to say that it is "50% true", in the same way as it's misleading for Coke to say "20% less sugar!*"

We could break out the components into new statements.

1. The Sun rose in the East yesterday.
2. The Sun set in the East yesterday.

And now we have one statement that is *entirely* false, and another that is *entirely* true. Again, no sliding scales down here.

One could argue that "truer" means a statement which contains more truths than another, but that's not right either; once broken apart, we are again comparing binaries.

Truth is more true than fallacy; everything else is haggling over the price.

Answer (score 0):

Ill-formed question. The question is just a pleonasm.

You ask for a "truest subjective truth": in such case, you are trying to find an *objective value of truth* ("truest...") *for an opinion* ("... subjective truth"). And that is just trying to find the opinion that is closest to truth. Then, your question reduces to "which opinion is closer to truth?"

Ergo, the answer is the result of a subjective choice: you choose which opinion is closer to *your own truth*. So, for you, "Markus is dumb" might seem farther from the truth than "Markus scored 82 points"; but not for me.

You have an additional problem, here: *ultimate truths are not accessible* [1]. If truth can't be known, how can you compare it to any opinion, in order to assess if it is closer to truth than another judgement?

If your question is addressed as two different problems (1: what do you call subjective truths types? and b) Which is the truest truth?), you will have:

a) *There's no general taxonomy of subjective truths.* Specific taxonomies might exist (arbitrary e.g.: individual-subjective, group-subjective, shared-subjective, etc.) might exist, but they are not considered in any representative philosophical discipline.

b) *In any case, a "truest truth" is contingent.* For a specific type within a selected taxonomy, validity (what "truest truth" would mean) depends on the approach. For example, shared-subjective can be more or less valid than individual-subjective, depending on the approach:

- a religious approach would grant eminence to individual-subjective (I saw a miracle, in spite of what people say, I am compelled to believe my subjective experience);
- a political approach would grant more eminence to shared-subjective (I saw a miracle, as a politician, I am compelled to discourage such idea in order for my politics to prevail, given that I should represent rationality).

Perhaps the most remarkable case of subjective truth is Descartes' *Cogito, ergo sum* [2] (I think, therefore I exist), which might be --arguably-- the "truest truth" we have access to. Try to apply your "truest truth" assessment to such truth compared with others, from different approaches. You'll find argument cases that make "markus scored 84" more and less valid.

[1] http://www.philosophypages.com/dy/t.htm#thing

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito,_ergo_sum